# save iis session data to disk

Tags: .net, session, iis-7, session-state, session-variables

I have a asp.net mvc site that being hosted via IIS 7.  I believe by default the session data is save in memory on the server.

Is there some way or setting to change so that IIS will save session data to disk?

Hope this makes sense.  I'm not a really server guy and don't understand a lot of the details of how sessions are managed on the server.   Any details / articles would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few different ways to do this.  You should probably take a look at [MSDN - Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

One of the options is to use SQL Server to persist across multiple IIS servers and/or when an AppPool is restarted (or server for that matter).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try to make the change to save it to disk.  If i make the change in the config that will save the session data to disk is there a way I can confirm that the session information is actually being saved there?  Would it be easy to confirm that the changes are actually taking effect?